# Laravel Route not defined error in resource controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have route file defined as follows...

`Route::get('pincodes/export', 'PincodeController@export'); Route::resource('pincodes','PincodeController');`

I have a controller called 'PincodeController' where the default functions works without any issue. I wanted to add a new function called 'export' in this controller. I tried {{ route('pincodes.export') }} in my blade file to generate link to this page... and it throws the following error...

`Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Route [pincodes.export] not defined. (View: /Users/tst/Desktop/www/laravel/project/resources/views/pincode/index.blade.php)`

but if i access the url directly in browser it works fine. why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically name the route:

```
Route::get('pincodes/export', 'PincodeController@export')->name('pincodes.export');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel 5.5+, change export route like this

```
Route::get('pincodes/export', 'PincodeController@export')->name('export');
```

use route function in your blade file like

```
route('export')
```